# Movement of a mass on a spring in damped SHM

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, integration, drag, oscillators, differential-equations

Suppose a ball is connected to a spring attached to a wall, and they are in space, i.e. assume no gravity. The ball is put into a fluid with Stoke's drag and oscillates backwards and forwards relative to the wall. The ball has a mass m and displacement x = acoswt. What would the displacement x be if ma = -kx-bv where b is a constant of drag force? How would you solve the differential equation?

Comment: It looks like you have the solution $x = a\cos(\omega t)$ given to  you: in which case just plug this into the equation and solve for $a$ and $\omega$ in terms of $m$, $k$ and $b$. Also $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$ and $a = \frac{dx^2}{d^2t}$